# WSO2 ESB Database Notifications

Tags: sql-server-2008, events, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I need to understand if it is possible for the WSO2 ESB to monitor a SQL Server 2008 database for table updates.  If an update is detected then the ESB will extract the changes from the SQL Server instance, transform them and deliver them as a message to a JMS queue.

I have been looking at the WSO2 Data Services but nothing describes this style of eventing

Any suggestions are welcome!